# Python: Import all objects from library by variable

Tags: python, import, python-importlib

I would like to import all objects from a library by variable.  I know how to import all objects from a library:

```
from package import *
```

I know how to import a library by variable:

```
import importlib

var = 'package'
package = importlib.import_module(var)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to combine these two goals.  It does not look like `importlib.import` supports this.  Can anyone help?

Note: I am aware of the dangers of skirting namespaces in this way (and anyone using potential answers to my inquiry should familiarize themselves with the dangers).  I only plan to use this for rapid development and testing of some algorithms, and plan to release my code with explicit names of individual objects from my files.

Edit: I came up with a minimal example. Suppose I have three files in the same directory:

aux1.py

```
var = 'aux2'
```

aux2.py

```
a = 0
b = 1
```

main.py

```
import importlib

from aux1 import var
aux2 = importlib.import_module(var)
```

If I run main.py, I can access `a` and `b` as `aux2.a` and `aux2.b`, but I'd like them to be globals instead.  What would the last line of `main.py` need to be in order to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the `__dict__` attribute of the module returned from `import_module`, and add that item to `globals()` if it doesn't start with `__`.

```
import importlib

var = 'package'
package = importlib.import_module(var)

for name, value in package.__dict__.items():
    if not name.startswith("__"):
        globals()[name] = value
```

If you only want to import certain members of `package`, you could use `getattr()` with a default of `None`:

```
imports = ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3']
for name in imports:
    value = getattr(package, name, None)
    if value is not None:
        globals()[name] = value
```

Comment: This strategy would certainly work, and it is the only idea I could come up with myself.  I wonder if there is a more built-in way to do this with the `importlib` (or some other) package though.  If it becomes clear that this is not the case, I will definitely accept your answer, since it works.

Comment: I don't think there's an inbuilt way to do it. If you really want to use this functionality very often, it's easy enough to put it in your own function / module. Since you don't plan to use this in production code anyway, I'd just put it in a module that sits on my local installation.

Answer (score -1):

```
import_module(name, package=None):
    """Import a module.
    The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
    specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
    relative import to an absolute import.
    """
```

This is the initialization of the `import_module(...)` method. Add a comma after name and put the location of the anchor point (a starting folder to reference the file from; for example "C:\Program Files\Java"). The second parameter basically acts like your from, only using absolute paths.

Comment: I can't understand your answer; I might not be fluent enough in Python yet.  It took me a while, but I came up with a minimal example that could facilitate a more concrete answer :)

Comment: That's not my downvote, by the way.